# Vertical sliders scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with a code which I've copied from http://jsfiddle.net/NGj7F/ I placed this code in my HTML file between  and I have put every section between

```
//Set each section's height equals to the window height
$('section').height($(window).height());
/*set the class 'active' to the first element 
 this will serve as our indicator*/
$('section').first().addClass('active');

/* handle the mousewheel event together with 
 DOMMouseScroll to work on cross browser */
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();//prevent the default mousewheel scrolling
  var active = $('section.active');
  //get the delta to determine the mousewheel scrol UP and DOWN
  var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;

  //if the delta value is negative, the user is scrolling down
  if (delta < 0) {
    //mousewheel down handler
    next = active.next();
    //check if the next section exist and animate the anchoring
    if (next.length) {
      /*setTimeout is here to prevent the scrolling animation
       to jump to the topmost or bottom when 
       the user scrolled very fast.*/
      var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        /* animate the scrollTop by passing 
        the elements offset top value */
        $('body, html').animate({
          scrollTop: next.offset().top
        }, 'slow');

        // move the indicator 'active' class
        next.addClass('active')
          .siblings().removeClass('active');

        clearTimeout(timer);
      }, 800);
    }

  } else {
    //mousewheel up handler
    /*similar logic to the mousewheel down handler 
    except that we are animate the anchoring 
    to the previous sibling element*/
    prev = active.prev();

    if (prev.length) {
      var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('body, html').animate({
          scrollTop: prev.offset().top
        }, 'slow');

        prev.addClass('active')
          .siblings().removeClass('active');

        clearTimeout(timer);
      }, 800);
    }

  }
});
```

It works as I want on my website with the exception that every time I arrive at the last section and scroll down again, after that it doesn't work anymore. The same happens when I try to scroll from the first section up. Why does it stop working? Please help!!! And can someone help me to introduce also the up and down arrows to this function? Thanks!!!!!